# JIRA Issue Event Listener

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I'm trying to make a JIRA Listener with [tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/guides/other/tutorial-writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library) but the tutorial is outdate and I've encoutered a problem. Plugin builds, installs but when I want to register Listener I'm getting

```
Class [com.example.tutorial.plugins.IssueCreatedResolvedListener] is not of type JiraListener.
```

I'm trying to do this on JIRA 6.4.13 but tutorial on JIRA 7.x would be also apprieciated.

Answer (score 0):

recent Jira versions uses Spring Scanner as described at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner. Generally, you should:

- in *pom.xml* add provided dependency for **atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation**
- create a Spring XML file in *src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/*;
- remove any **component-import** from *atlassian-plugin.xml*;
- instead of removed **component-import**, add **@Component** annotation to your listener class;
- you class should implement **InitializingBean**, **DisposableBean** and **LifecycleAware** interfaces;
- overide **afterPropertiesSet()** to register your listener.

So, your code should looks like this

```
@ExportAsService
@Component
@Named("IssueCreatedResolvedListener")
public class IssueCreatedResolvedListener implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean, LifecycleAware {
    @ComponentImport
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
    @ComponentImport
    private final EventPublisher eventPublisher;
    @ComponentImport
    protected final LifecycleManager lifecycleManager;

    @Inject
    public IssueCreatedResolvedListener(final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties, final EventPublisher eventPublisher,
        final LifecycleManager lifecycleManager) {
        this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        this.lifecycleManager = lifecycleManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        eventPublisher.register(this);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onIssueEvent(IssueEvent issueEvent) {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Hope this helps!